# Bootstrap 4 horizontal text alignment is not working in <span>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've the following code:

```
   <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-block">    
            <h4 class="card-title">
                <span class="text-left"></span>
                <span class="text-right">Drago</span>
            </h4>
            <span class="card-text">
                Location: ???<br>
                District: ???<br>
                Last updated: Tue, May 8th 2018
            </span><br><br>
            <div class="card-buttons" class="text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Edit User</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Manage Addresses</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to make a card in Bootstrap 4.

I do want the emoji in the `<h4>` to be aligned left and the text after it to be aligned to the right. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
<h4 class="card-title">
    <span class="text-left"></span>
    <span class="text-right">Drago</span>
</h4>
```

But this is not working, I get:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/x5FOJuy.png]

I also tried to do it without the bootstrap classes. Using `style="text-align: left"` and `style="text-align: right"`. However this also doesn't seem to work.

When I use `<div>` the horizontal alignment works fine. I get this problem only with `<span>` and `<div>`s that have display property set to `inline-block` and `inline-flex`.

Comment: simple add display:block to the span

Comment: `<span>` is an inline-block element; its default width will always be just enough for its contents. `text-right` won't work unless you modify this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `float-right` because the `.card-title` is `display:block`...

```
<h4 class="card-title">
        <span></span>
        <span class="float-right">Drago</span>
</h4>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/CMrl4JydKp

Using `text-right` works on the parent of an inline element.

Answer (score 2):

```
.card-title {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text-right {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

You would probably want to add custom classes to the card-title for example, so you are not adjusting all card titles in general.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2xv2t12c/

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!!

BS4 update:- Added .float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none} classes for responsive floats and removed .pull-left and .pull-right since they’re redundant to .float-left and .float-right.

So use float right and also i added a br tag under h4 so the below span wouldn't overflow into h4.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title ">
      <span class="float-left"></span>
      <span class="float-right">Drago</span>
    </h4>
    <br/>
    <span class="card-text">
                Location: ???<br>
                District: ???<br>
                Last updated: Tue, May 8th 2018
            </span><br><br>
    <div class="card-buttons" class="text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Edit User</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Manage Addresses</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```